# Max Payne No Gameplay on Windows 7

Tags: pc, windows-7, max-payne

I have a physical disc copy of Max Payne 1. The disc does not work with Windows 7. I searched many gaming forums and their answers have not given me any success.

The PC I'm trying to run it on has 8GB of Ram and a 1 TB HDD. The PC is running Windows 7 Home 64-bit.

I have installed Max Payne from the file directly on the disc called "Disk1" as suggested in many forums. I have run the setup application from "Disk1" with success of installing the program.

I have changed the resolution and the PC to 16 bit color mode. A Yes or No dialog box comes up when I click the Max Payne link on the Start menu. I click Yes to verify I accept the Max Payne application. The screen flashes and the time circle like the old sand hourglass comes up and spins.

A resolution change occurs that makes the desktop have larger icons. Then the desktop goes back to its more modern resolution.

Nothing happens after the screen flashes back to its regular resolution. Its like the Max Payne process or service stops completely.

Answer (score 1):

The physical release uses [SafeDisc DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SafeDisc), no longer supported by Microsoft:

http://www.howtogeek.com/230773/how-to-play-pc-games-that-require-safedisc-or-securom-drm-on-windows-10-8.1-8-7-and-vista/

Publisher Rockstar actually "cracked" the game for the Steam release, it seems:

[image]